# How to use Mongodb::cursor in Rust?

Tags: mongodb, rust

It's a very simple project to learn how to use mongodb with Rust. I'm using the official mongodb driver here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-rust-driver. The problem is that if I'm using `aggregate`, I cannot read the result

```
// main.rs
use mongodb::bson::{doc, Bson};
use mongodb::{options::AggregateOptions, options::ClientOptions, Client};
use std::error::Error;
use tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

   // Load the MongoDB connection string:
   let client_uri = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";

   // A Client is needed to connect to MongoDB:
   let mut options = ClientOptions::parse(&client_uri).await?;
   options.app_name = Some("testing".to_string());
   let client = Client::with_options(options)?;
   
   // get the collection here
   let items = client.database("my_database").collection("inventory");

   // aggregate options and pipeline
   let pipeline = vec![doc! {"$match": {"name": "FOO"}}];
   let options = AggregateOptions::builder().allow_disk_use(true).build();

   // I'm using tokio for async-await library
   let data = items
      .aggregate(pipeline, options)
      .await
      .map_err(|e| println!("{}", e));

    // data is a Result<mongodb::Cursor> type
    match data {
       Ok(cursor) => {
        
          // I want to iterate the returned documents here
          // this doesn't compiles
          while let Some(doc) = cursor.next().await {
              println!("{}", doc?)
          }
       },
       Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
}
```

The code above returns an error. It complains that the cursor has no `next()` function within.

```
 while let Some(doc) = cursor.next().await {
   |                          ^^^^ method not found in `mongodb::Cursor`
```

I read the manual book for mongodb::Cursor here: https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.2.1/mongodb/struct.Cursor.html

and aggregate function here https://docs.rs/mongodb/1.2.1/mongodb/struct.Collection.html#method.aggregate

As you can see the aggregate method should return `Result<Cursor>`. As the manual stated:

> A cursor can be used like any other Stream. The simplest way is just
> to iterate over the documents it yields:

```
while let Some(doc) = cursor.next().await {
  println!("{}", doc?)
}
```

So why is it doesn't work ?

My dependencies in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
tokio = { version = "0.2", features = ["macros", "rt-threaded"]  }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
mongodb = "1.2.0"
```

If I print the cursor `println!("{:?}", cursor);`. It contains data in it. How to get the data out from this cursor ?

Comment: That looks like the syntax used in the docs, but are you sure you've used all the correct dependencies?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's correct. I can find a single document with `find_one()` just above this code

Comment: I say that because sometimes certain features require a `use` to function correctly. If the example is broken, check that you're using the same version as in the docs.

Comment: well... if that's the case then I can't see any from the documentation. Maybe I miss something

Comment: Can you add your `use` line in your code sample with an edit? It's missing currently.

Comment: OK. already done.

Comment: ah... I found it! You're right!!! It needs to use `use tokio::stream::StreamExt;` since cursor are an implementation of `futures::stream::Stream`

Comment: Worth adding as a self-answer as you put in the work digging that up.

Comment: Update: StreamExt was moved out of tokio, into tokio_stream. So you can add that crate and use `use tokio_stream::StreamExt` or most likely if you already have the futures crate, you can still use `use futures::stream::StreamExt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! Just add `use tokio::stream::StreamExt;` on top of the file and the rest is good to go.

> ...all the other methods that an Stream has are available on Cursor as
> well. This includes all of the functionality provided by StreamExt,
> which provides similar functionality to the standard library Iterator
> trait.

```
// main.rs
use mongodb::bson::{doc, Bson};
use mongodb::{options::AggregateOptions, options::ClientOptions, Client};
use std::error::Error;
use tokio;

// don't forget this!
use tokio::stream::StreamExt;
```